# What is the role of versionMapping in maven-publish plugin

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-publish

What option would be preferable, if we have to generate a java library using maven-publish plugin

Option 1:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                allVariants {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the role of `versionMapping` in `maven-publish` plugin

Per the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:resolved_dependencies):

> Two strategies are supported for publishing dependencies:
>
> -- snip
>
> This is done by using the `versionMapping` DSL method

> What option would be preferable

That is entirely dependent on your use case/needs. As mentioned in the docs, there are two strategies for dependencies: declared versions and resolved versions. Which one you use is entirely dependent on your use case or needs.